# Program behaving abnormally due to weird async nature of nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, database

I get a post from mongodb then using that post's id I get the likes on that post, my postlikes object contains a "post" and the "likedby" array that contains usernames of people who liked it. The problem is that when i get a post, the callback for getting likes on it is somehow complex thats why node runs ahead and I couldn't get the likes i always get likes of the last post in the db mostly because the loop has reached its end then my callback is called for likes. Any solution for this??

```
for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++)
   {
       db.collection('likes',function(err,likesCollec){
       console.log("before likes posts[i].post",posts[i].post);
       function wait(done){
           while(done);
       }
       done=true;
       likesCollec.find({postid:(posts[i]._id).toString()})
       .toArray(function(err,likes){
        console.log("posts[i].post:",posts[i].post);
        postlikes[i].post=posts[i].post;
        console.log("postlikes[i].post: ",postlikes[i].post);
          for(j=0;j<likes.length;j++)
            {
                postlikes[i].likedby[j]=likes[j].username;
            }
        console.log(postlikes[i]);
        done=false;
        wait(done);
            });
        });
        if(i==(posts.length)-1)
        {
            return res.json(posts);
        }
    }
```

The wait function isn't working properly also maybe I am going to the wrong direction, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `bluebird`;

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Var p = Promise.resolve();
forEach(posts, function(item, index, arr) {
    p.then(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         // do here in sync.


          resolve();  //in last
    }));
});
p.then(function(){
   // all tasks launched in the loop are finished.
   // do extra here.
});
```

Comment: So in forEach I wil do the likes thing and what happens in then? sending response or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Use async forEach
https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

```
async = require('async');
async.forEach(posts,function(post, callback){
      // Do functionality here
      return callback();
})
```

Comment: callback as in a function or what?

Comment: callback is a function